# Finding all children for multiple parents in single SQL query and Linq query

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, self-referencing-table

I need to `SELECT` query using `LINQ` and also `SQL` resulting as:

```
ParentId   Country   State         ChildId
 1         India     kerala           2
 1         India     TamilNamdu       3
 5         Pakistan  Kasagithan1      6
 5         Pakistan  Kasg2            7
```

And my `Table` is:

```
Id  ParentId Country        State
1   0        India          NULL
2   1        NULL           Kerala
3   1        NULL           TamilNamdu
4   1        NULL           Karnadaka
5   0        Pakisthan      NULL
6   5        NULL           Kasagithan
7   5        NULL           Kasg2
8   5        NULL           Afganistha
9   0        China          NULL
10  9        NULL           Hwuesang1
11  9        NULL           sate1
12  9        NULL           sate2
```

Comment: I suggest you change your design. You can assume every `Country`, `State` is a single entity (Table)

Comment: i am using parent and child table is single table

Comment: Well yes but what's the advantage besides the trouble it brings?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `SQL` query:

```
select parentid, country, state, childID 
from tablename 
where parentid IN (1,5)
```

Comment: It will retrieve all the rows that has ID 5 and 1 .

Comment: -1: `it will retrieve all the rows that has ID 5 and 1` which should be `ID 1 to 5 (between 1 to 5)` which in case isn't the correct answer for the question. The question is about relating states with their countries not filtering IDs

Comment: @Yuvi you are welcome but altho it's corrected now, it still doesn't give the answer for the question. The result will be *states of India and Pakisthan* with `Country` field `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

In SQL a self join should do it:

```
SELECT P.Id AS ParentId, P.Country, C.State, C.Id AS ChildId
FROM table AS P
JOIN table as C ON C.ParentId = P.Id AND C.ParentId <> 0
WHERE P.State IS NULL
```

Comment: @Federik, thanks i have tested it i got result in sql

Answer (score 1):

You can *self-join* the table using `Id` and `ParentId` columns. The following code is `LINQ` implementation of this approach:

```
using (YourEntity yourEntity = new YourEntity())
{
    var result =
    (
        from state in yourEntity.YourTableName
        from country in yourEntity.YourTableName
        where state.ParentId != 0 && state.ParentId == country.Id
        select new { ParentId = state.ParentId, Country = country.Country, State = state.State, ChildId = state.Id }
    ).ToList();
}
```

You can test the result using `Console`: (or change it with `Debug.WriteLine()` to see results in output window if you can't use console)

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", item.ParentId, item.Country, item.State, item.ChildId);
}
```

And for `SQL` Query you can use:

```
SELECT state.ParentId, country.Country, state.State, state.Id As 'ChildId'
FROM YourTableName As state INNER JOIN YourTableName AS country
    ON state.ParentId <> 0 AND state.ParentId = country.Id
```

Comment: @Sajith Hope you will (: